# vi/vim, how can I write out a number of lines to a new file

Tags: vim, files, editors, vi

While in an active Vim buffer, how can I write out a specific range of lines to a new file without closing the current buffer first?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do

```
:100,200w filename
```

Of course 100,200 is the range of lines you want to write.

Comment: Are the addresses inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Inclusive.  Also inclusive if you use patterns: :/^something/,/^else/ w filename, or marks:  'a,'b w filename  includes the lines marked 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Hi @Bernhard, what if i want to cut lines from current file.

Comment: Is there a notation that means "this line until the end of the file"? Or even: "the cursor's present position to the end of the file"?

Comment: @felwithe - yes, for example :.,$ w file.txt  That is "." for current line and "$" for "end of file".  You can swap out line numbers for either "." or "$" as needed.

Comment: Just like any other command on a range, it also works on visually selected lines `:'<,'>w filename`

Answer (score 28):

The most general:

1. Move cursor to first line of the group you want to write. Hit `m`
   and `a` sequentiall.  That's "set mark named 'a'".
2. Move cursor to last line of the group, hit 'm' and 'b'.'
3. Change over to command mode hit: as a sequence do `:'a,'b w
   filename` then hit return.

That will work in vi, nvi and vim.

Another method, works in more modern vim:

1. Put cursor on first line of the group of lines you want to write out. Hit `V`, for "start visual block of lines".
2. Move cursor to the bottom of the group of lines.  Vim will highlight with reverse video each line.
3. Write out.  Hit `:` to go into command line mode.  That will give you a prompt at the bottom of the scren that looks like: `:'<,'>`  That means from the start of the visual block to the end.  Type `w` and the filename and hit return.

You can add  singled lines to the end of the file as you need to by putting your cursor on the line you want to write out then typing: `:.w >> filename` and hitting return.

The "write a group of lines" commands also work with ">> filename" instead of just "filename".  The ">>" causes vi or vim to append to the file, rather than just writing it.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the line numbers that you want to write, you can do it from the command line:

```
vim -c "100,200w new_file.txt" -c wq original_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One small trick is to use relative line numbers.  For example:

```
:+0,+99w filename
```

writes the next 100 lines to *filename*.

Comment: Won't that overwrite the original file? The OP would like to write out to a different file.

Comment: @SabreWolfy No; maybe you missed 'filename' after the line numbers. I just tested his version and it worked.